# Fill class properties generated from XSD.exe

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

OK, I generated C# classes from my huge XSD file. Now I have a set of C# classes, XSD schema and actual XML data. Is there an automatic or semi-automatic way to fill these class instances with XML data that I have?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have used `xsd.exe` to generate the classes, then `XmlSerializer` should do the job...

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootType));
RootType type = (RootType) ser.Deserialize(source)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the xml serialization/deserialization to export/import data to xml. Take a look at the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class. An example is on the msdn page.